# Using lambda with .apply() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, I am trying to apply this lambda function, using .apply() and I am getting this error: 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
(beers[:10] - beers.mean()).apply(lambda x: 'low' if x < 0 else 'high')
```

beers is a series.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to add axis=1 param in the apply func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beers` is not a `Series` else you code work well. It's certainly a `DataFrame` and probably a `DataFrame` with only one column.

Demo:

```
>>> beers = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 10, 20))

>>> type(beers)
pandas.core.series.Series

>>> (beers[:10] - beers.mean()).apply(lambda x: 'low' if x < 0 else 'high')
0    high
1     low
2    high
3     low
4    high
5    high
6     low
7    high
8    high
9     low
dtype: object
```

Now if `beers` is a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> beers = beers.to_frame()

>>> type(beers)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

>>> (beers[:10] - beers.mean()).apply(lambda x: 'low' if x < 0 else 'high')
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

In the case where `beers` has only one column, you can use `squeeze`:

```
>>> (beers[:10] - beers.mean()).squeeze().apply(lambda x: 'low' if x < 0 else 'high')
0    high
1     low
2    high
3     low
4    high
5    high
6     low
7    high
8    high
9     low
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this
if beers is a series if it is a df you will need column name as well

```
beers_mean = beers.mean()
beers[:10].apply(lambda x: 'low' if (x-beers_mean)<0 else 'high'
```

it cant resultve the beers[:10] - beers.mean() into a new series that why you got an exception

if beers is a DF and you want to do this on a single column in the table then
just picked it first

```
beer_col = beers[['col_name']]
beers_mean = beer_col .mean()
beer_col[:10].apply(lambda x: 'low' if (x-beers_mean)<0 else 'high'
```